# window.open is not working in ionic for ios

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

window open is not working in ionic for ios application.

My code is :

```
var ref = $window.open(url, '_system', 'location=no,toolbar=yes');
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('myController',function($http,$scope,$state,$ionicLoading,$cordovaOauth,$ionicPopup,$window,$ionicHistory,$cordovaCamera,$ionicPlatform,$timeout,$cordovaInAppBrowser,$rootScope,$cordovaDevice,Notification)
```

Comment: You need to add more context. What does it do? Does the code get executed? Does a window open?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add [Cordova Inappbrowser](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/) in order to use it.

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

or

```
window.open('http://apache.org','_system','location=no');
```

Make sure to check `deviceready state` or (for ionic) `$ionicPlatform.ready` before using it.